# Yacs Libraryis not included in standard RHEL distribution

Tags: ibm-unix-system-services

Today morning asking the admin of our server if they could install a library that is missing to run our python code. The answer war, they couldnt do that cause:

*"This library is not included in standard RHEL distribution"*

What does it means ? Why is the reason cause that library is not include and all the othes do ?

Comment: Only the RHEL developers at IBM/Redhat can know the answer to that question.  It's probably something like "Nobody at Redhat knew about the library. Or if they did, nobody there thought it was worth the effort of making a package of it.  Or there's a similar library in RHEL that they prefer".

Comment: Is your actual question then "How can I have them install the library by hand, or do it myself for my user only without admin privileges"?

Comment: @AdminBee , no. My actual question was to understand the problematic under that phrase that I could not understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases, *libraries* are only included in distributions such as RHEL because they are required by another package which is desirable to have in the distribution. This is always worth bearing in mind as a general rule: the packages available in a distribution, in particular libraries, are there for the distributions’ purposes, which is to ultimately provide a working environment for end-users, not as general-purpose *development* tools.

So the basic answer is that [YACS](https://github.com/rbgirshick/yacs) isn’t included in RHEL because nothing else in RHEL requires it, and no end-user use-case was made to support its inclusion.

A consequence of the general rule I mentioned above is that libraries included in a distribution aren’t necessarily appropriate for third-party programs. In Python’s case in particular, it’s often worth using [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) instead; those can have whichever Python modules are required, without affecting the system’s.

(I’m ignoring [Software Collections](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/overview) here; these *are* designed for development use-cases, but they still don’t include YACS.)